# Measure the width of a string in a WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, image, drawing

I have a service that needs to construct some data to be printed.  Part of the logic for this includes truncating data that gets too large.

So, in my WCF service, I need a way to do a Graphics.MeasureString on a 200 dpi surface.

**Is there a way to construct a generic (barebones) Image that is 200 dpi so that I can measure string widths in Arial Narrow 13pt Bold?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this does it:

```
// Set up string. 
string measureString = "Measure String";
Font stringFont = new Font("ArialNarrow", 13, FontStyle.Bold);

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100,100);
bitmap.SetResolution(200,200);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

// Measure string.
SizeF stringSize = new SizeF();
stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont);
```